# SASS Literal Strings

Tags: sass, django-compressor

I'm using Django with django-compressor and pySCSS to compile SASS to regular CSS.

In django-compressor there's a filter that can convert variables like `{{ STATIC_URL }}` to the actual value. Unfortunately that runs after the SASS precompiler.

When I put in that literal in the `.sass` file, it inserts whitespaces between the curly braces:

```
background-image: url('{{ STATIC_URL }}img/background-lines.png')
```

becomes

```
background-image:url(' { { STATIC_URL }}img/background-lines.png')
```

Is there a way to insert a literal string into SASS source files? Or a way to escape the curly braces so they're not changed?

Comment: what do you think about to use grunt or other outer compile instruments? you can adjust "watch" task in these instruments and compile sass files whenever you want.

Comment: I think the templatefilter makes more sense used as a precompiler (I want to use it this way too). Looks like someone else is having troubles using it that way though: https://github.com/django-compressor/django-compressor/issues/533